# Greater than lesser than comparison in floating points in C

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

```
float x = 0.1;
if ( x> 0.1){
    printf("if");
}
```

Now when I check equality, it is explained that x is being converted to double by padding 0s at the end, but 0.1 on RHS is stored in double, hence the inequality.
But if I go through this logic, the "if" in the above code should have given false, but istead it is true.
Why?

Comment: floats are not perfectly precise.  They cannot represent every number and so there will be rounding errors.  In this case, it apparently rounded up to a value just a tiny bit greater than `0.1`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons -- note that the constant `0.1` is also a floating point value, represented inexactly as a `double`.

Comment: @DavidBowling Indeed.  That was an error of omission on my part.

Comment: It's just an oversight that rounding (up) already happens with `float x = 0.1;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Restricting the answer to IEEE754 although all floating point schemes supported by C mandate that the `double` set is a superset of the `float` set.)

`0.1` is `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`

`0.1f` is `0.100000001490116119384765625`.

`0.100000001490116119384765625` is promoted to a `double`, but it's the same number as all `float`s can be represented as `double`s exactly.

So `(double)(0.1f)` is bigger than `0.1`, accounting for the result.

Answer (score 2):

The key issue is that `0.1` can't be represented **exactly** in binary. Converting this to base 2, you get a number with a *repetend* in the fraction part, `1001` is repeating forever (just like in decimal, `1/3` ends up with `3` repeating forever).

When storing `0.1` in a float, it ends up getting *rounded up* in the last digit *), therefore the `float` 0.1 is larger than the `double` 0.1

So, yes, converting the `float` to `double` just appends (binary) zeros, but the `float` was already a bit too large in the first place.

---

*) this actually depends on the representation of floating point numbers your implementation uses. With IEEE 754 `float`s, the representation would end with

```
... 10011001100
```

and because the next digit would be a 1, rounding is done upwards, so the final result ends with

```
... 10011001101
```

Comment: The phrasing “a period in the fraction part” made me think there was a “.” in the fraction part. I think it would be clearer to say that the binary digits in the fraction part continue forever, with a repeating pattern.

Comment: @EricPostpischil mindless direct translation of the german word, the mathematical languages differ :( In german, it's indeed a "period" (in the sense of a uniformly repeating pattern); I just looked it up, in english it's called a "repetend" ...

Comment: Well, I just learned a new word.